# undefined offset notice, how to replace it with an empty table row

Tags: php, html

```
$arrQuestionContent = array();
$arrAnswerFile = array();


while ($qandaqrystmt->fetch()) {
    $arrQuestionId[] = $qandaQuestionId;
    $arrQuestionContent[] = $qandaQuestionContent;
}

...

while ($imgqrystmt->fetch()) {
  $arrAnswer[] = $AnswerFile;
}
```

Above I have two arrays which fetchs data from db, `arrQuestionContent[]` fetched all questions while `$arrAnswer[]` fetches all answers per question.

But some questions may contain no answers which leads to an `Notice: Undefined offset:` for each question row in my table which does not contain an answer.

My question is that if a question row does not contain an answer, how can I get the table to display a blank row under the `Answer` column?

Also there is a possibility that a question has multiple answers. If that is the case then I want the question row which has multiple answers to be able to include all of its answers under the `Answer` column within the question row. At the moment it is only display one answer for a question row which is suppose to have multiple answers:

Below is the table:

```
    <table id="tableqanda" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="30%" class="question">Question</th>
        <th width="12%" class="images">Answer</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
          foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {
        echo '<tr class="tableqandarow">'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td width="30%" class="question">'.htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionContent[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td width="12%" class="images">'. ( empty ($arrAnswerFile[$key]) ) ? "&nbsp;" : htmlspecialchars( is_array( $arrAnswerFile[$key] ) ? implode(",", $arrAnswerFile[$key]) : $arrAnswerFile[$key] ) . '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
        }
?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

**UPDATE:**

Screenshot showing what table should look like:

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

Result of `var_dump($arrQuestionContent);`:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(19) "Name these 2 things" [1]=> string(11) "What is 4+4" }
```

Result of `var_dump($arrAnswerFile);`:

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> string(1) "A" 
[1]=> string(1) "C" 
[2]=> string(1) "A" 
}
```

Below is screenshot of table. This happens no matter if the question has an answer(s) or not:

[image]

Database:

```
QuestionId  QuestionContent         Answer
1           Name these 2 Things     A
1           Name these 2 Things     C
2           What is 4+4?            A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following our chat discussion we have fixed a part of the problem, which is assigning each answer to its question, for the rest, case of multiple answers, please use the following code:

```
while ($qandaqrystmt->fetch()) { 
    $arrQuestionId[ $qandaQuestionId ] = $qandaQuestionId; 
    $arrQuestionNo[ $qandaQuestionId ] = $qandaQuestionNo; 
    $arrQuestionContent[ $qandaQuestionId ] = $qandaQuestionContent; 
    $arrOptionType[ $qandaQuestionId ] = $qandaOptionType; 
}
...
while ($imgqrystmt->fetch()) { 
    $arrImageFile[ $imgQuestionId ][] = basename($imgImageFile); 
}
```

and then you show the elements in your HTML table with the following:

```
foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) { 
    echo '<tr class="tableqandarow">'.PHP_EOL; 
    echo '<td width="5%" class="questionno">'.htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionNo[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL; 
    echo '<td width="27%" class="question">'.htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionContent[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL; 
    echo '<td width="7%" class="option">'.htmlspecialchars($arrOptionType[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL; 
    echo '<td width="11%" class="imagetd">'. ( ( empty ($arrImageFile[$key]) ) ? "&nbsp;" : '<ul class="qandaul"><li>'.htmlspecialchars( is_array( $arrImageFile[$key] ) ? implode(" ", $arrImageFile[$key]) : $arrImageFile[$key] ) ). '</li></ul></td>' . PHP_EOL; 
    echo '</tr>'.PHP_EOL; 
    }
```

I hope this works now, if not just tell me what it gives

Answer (score 1):

in order to show an empty cell, you can do the following:

```
echo '<td>'. ( empty ($arrAnswerFile[$key]) ) ? "&nbsp;" : htmlspecialchars( $arrAnswerFile[$key] ) . '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
```

for the other case, to show the multiple answers, how to do store theme ?
if your $arrAnswerFile[$key] variable is an array you can do the following to solve it:

```
echo '<td>'. ( ( empty ($arrAnswerFile[$key]) ) ? "&nbsp;" : htmlspecialchars( is_array( $arrAnswerFile[$key] ) ? implode(",", $arrAnswerFile[$key]) : $arrAnswerFile[$key] ) ). '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
```

and the answers will be displayed separated by a comma, but if you store the answer in another way, please tell us that we can propose a better solution

Comment: Hi, I included your last line you provided into the application but problem is that no table row is appearing for answer at all? No matter is there is or no answers it does not display the rows for answer

Comment: Let me show you a screenshot showing how I want the table to look

Comment: Included a screenshote on what table should look like

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of what you actually got ?

Comment: Also please provide the content of var_dump($arrQuestionContent) and var_dump($arrAnswerFile) ?

Comment: what about var_dump($arrAnswerFile) ?

Comment: I have included that in update. So if you look at the var_dump, Answers `A` and `C` go in question 1 and the other Answer `A` go in question 2.

Comment: hum... as I see first answer "A" should be assigned with question 1, and "C" goes to question 2, but the second "A" has no question ?!! is that true ? or did I miss something ? give me sometime I'll be back and make some tests to see what's wrong !

Comment: Seems like that is what it is doing. The arrays contains data from the database results which I included in update. What should happen by determining a question's id, in the html/php table it should display the question content and answer(s) for each answer. So `A` and `C` go in question 1 and bottom `A` goes in question 2

Comment: Sorry for answering late, the reason you got an empty answer is due to a missing parenthesizes in my previous code, I corrected it and now should be okay, please let me know if it still not working for you

Comment: Hi, sorry I have been a sleep, I will test it and get back to you with outcome :)

Comment: Hi, only issue I am recieving now is that in the example we was going through not both answers A and C are appearing within question 1, only Answer A in question 1, answer C in question 2 and then the bottom Answer A which should of been in question 2 does not appear at all

Comment: Yes, I could guess, the problem is in your logic building the arrays and filling them, you are making things in the wrong way, perhaps we can move to chat, and I can manage to help you

Comment: Yeah ok I will come into chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23110/discussion-between-user1964964-and-abu-romaissae)

Comment: Sorry I did not notice you was in chat. I am in chat now so just come into chat when you are ready

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear how the variables $qandaQuestionContent and $AnswerFile are set (gets value).

Perhaps you should modify the two **while** loops mentioned in the question to get value for $qandaQuestionContent and $AnswerFile.

Comment: The data comes from the database, I get the values but it is just that I get an error for each row where a question has no answer. If question has an answer then there is no errors in that row. Do you want me to show you the mysqli code where the data is retrieved?